# Why does the SSL certificate chain has always at least 2 sub-CAs?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, certificate-authority

I've noticed that in my browser the SSL certificate chain has always at least 2 sub-CAs. Is that always the case? If true, does someone know why?

Comment: Would this be better on ServerFault, since it's more about administering the CA infrastructure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is often at least an intermediate CA, because it can make it easier to manage subsidiaries and to manage roll overs, but this is not a requirement.